# Access from DataTemplate to another property

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have VM class, where are three classes A, B and C; B derived from A. I need to access a property called IsAdditional in class A which is an abstract class from the DataTemplate class C.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type paper:C_class}">
         <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding From, Converter={x:Static c:NullToCollapsedConverter.Instance}}">
               <Run Text="{Binding PropFromC_class, Converter={x:Static c:StationConverters.ShortName}, Mode=OneWay}" />
               <InlineUIContainer>  
    //No acces here for IsAdditional
                    <TextBlock  Visibility="{Binding Path=IsAdditional, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" >
                       <Run Text="X" />
                     </TextBlock> 
               </InlineUIContainer>
           </TextBlock>
  </DataTemplate>
```

I have declared DataTemplate from B class also:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type paper:B_class}">
      <InlineUIContainer>
           <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding IsAdditional, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                <Run Text="X"/>
           </TextBlock>
        </InlineUIContainer>
  </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: What is the error or problem you are facing?

Comment: You can only bind to something that is concrete.  So where is your abstract class instantiated?

Comment: @AQuirky abstract class is in VM class.

Comment: @Colwin I don't have acces to IsAdditional property from C_class template.

Comment: The DataTemplate for C_class only gets applied to objects of type C_class and if there is no IsAdditional property defined in this class or any of its base classes, you obviously cannot bind to such a property. For C to be able to know any property that is defined in A, C should be derive from A.

Comment: @mm8 ok, clear answer. I thought that is some tricks to do that.

Comment: @p__d: I am afraid there is no "trick" to be able to bind to a property that is completely unknown to the type (class) that represents the DataContext of the DataTemplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataTemplate` for `C_class` only gets applied to objects of type `C_class` and if there is no `IsAdditional` property defined in this class or any of its base classes, you obviously cannot bind to such a property.

For `C_class` to be able to know any property that is defined in `A_class`, `C_class` should derive from `A_class`.

Comment: Yeap, I've had to change something in my VM, that's not looking good, but works :)